# how to display more than image in JFrame?

Tags: java, image, swing, jtree, jfilechooser

To display all the contents of a folder of .jpg files, should I use a `JFileChooser` or `JTree`?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Where's the problem? What did you try so far?

Comment: at now i can just diplay one picture.... that i selected with jfilechooser... but what i want is, when i select one picture, i want to import in jframe also the rest of the content of the folder. i dont know if i explain good my problem or not :s thank for help

Comment: You could get the parent folder of the selected file and then iterate over that folder's content ...

Comment: See also [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use JFileChooser, you need to put JButton and JLabel on JPanel (use GridBagLayout http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), after this you must add to JButton ActionListener. In the listener you will call your JFileChooser and after that you can display selected images on the JLabel.

In JFileChooser use file filter http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JFileChoosersetFileFilterFileFilterfilter.htm

Comment: plz look to the picture... this is what i want to do!!! you think its can work???

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use `JTree`. Using `JFileChooser`, you are too limited.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display multiple images (e.g. in a `JPanel`) then you need to set an appropriate [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) so that the images are arranged correctly.

Then read all the files in the directory and load the JPEGs into `ImageIcon`s.

Then add the `ImageIcon`s to your container (probably by creating `JLabel`s)

If you need more specific help on one of these steps, please ask a more specific question.